# Disserializing POJO with Lombok sending complex JSON using Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, lombok, rest-assured

This is my first use of POJO and Lombok with Rest Assured and complex JSON.

I decided to use this approach because JSON contains many fields..

Example JSON

```
{"records":[{"key":"1563106","value":{"ACTION":"A"}}]}
```

The "value" object contains about 50 fields.

Using POJO I have created 3 classes

```
public class TransactionFields{
private List<RecordsItem> records;}


public class RecordsItem {
private Object value;
private String key;}


public class Value{
private String ACTION;}
```

By adding annotations to each of them

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

Then I try to send a POST request using Rest Assured and do it this way:

1. Create a Value object and add a value (I will repeat a lot more fields here)

   ```
     Value value = Value.builder()
             .ACTION("A")
             .build();
   ```
2. 

```
 RecordsItem records = RecordsItem.builder()
                  .key("1563106")
                  .value(value)
                  .build();
```

And I send a POST request

```
given()
            .contentType("application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json")
            .body(records).
            when().post("V02")
            .then().log().all().statusCode(200);
```

As a result, I get the error

```
"error_code": 422,
"message": "Unrecognized field: value"
```

This is where the problems begin.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
and the most important question.
Am I using the build pattern correctly?
And is the correct object passed to POST ()?

Please help me figure it out. There are no problems with simple JSON examples, but I have not found an example with JSON that contains an array of objects.

Comment: Could u use JsonNode in `Object value` ?

Comment: @kidnan1991,   do not understand you. what do you mean?
`Object value = Value.builder()`?

Comment: Pardon me, i was misunderstanding your question. I thought it was deserialization to POJO.
 Am I using the build pattern correctly? => Since u use lombok, Builder pattern is used correctly
 And is the correct object passed to POST () => I doubt the body should include `TransactionFields` as records key

Comment: Maybe you should provide your rest-assured version and your "V02" uri interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I understood what my mistake was ...

In this implementation, I needed to change the type of the value object to Value in the RecordsItem class.

```
public class RecordsItem {
private Value value;
private String key;
```

And create another object of type TransactionFields

```
TransactionFields transactionFields = TransactionFields.builder()
            .records(Arrays.asList(records))
            .build();
```

And after that use the transactionFields variable in the post request body

```
.body(transactionFields)
```